# Problem with TopNavigation menu

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page

I have custom master page  .. it's everything ok  in site pages , but 
when i open pop up dialog forms to add list item or theme  my TopNavigationMenu is visible in dialog it.

How can i modify to hide or remove it from all dialog forms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the CSS class 's4-notdlg' to your html elements that should not be visible when the page is displayed as a dialog

Comment: As [this blog](http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/2011/10/s4-notdlg-not-doing-what-it-should-be-doing/) pointed out, you may also need to add `runat = "server` to your <html> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add `s4-notdlg` class to the `div` that you wish to hide in your master page.

- s4-notdlg - This class when added with other classes in your master page, will eliminate that particular class from appearing in the modal dialog.